# How to set checkbox value inside Combobox Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik

I have taken multiselect combobox in Rad telerik control.
ie: checkbox inside combobox item

The problem which i am facing is related to setting value of checkbox, from viewmodel.  I am using MVVM pattern, so i am not able to find the binding relationship.
In form Add  mode it will fine because there is not setting value in check box. but in edit mode i collect selected value list from database and set it to combobox. but i am not able to set value. any idea for that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like, if using MVVM, you need some sort of wrapping collection in your ViewModel that let you easily bind to that checkbox.

Comment: Thanks NestorArturo, I already do it. But event is not fire.. Any idea??

Comment: Which event are you talking about?